# Get the URL(s) from Firefox using C# .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, firefox, .net-3.5

I am writing a .NET 3.5 WPF application in C#.  This application needs to be able to get the URL(s) out of the browser window when it is in the foreground.

I already have the code working that handles a global Windows hotkey and then checks to see if the foreground IntPtr is from a browser.  If so, I am able to obtain the System.Diagnostics.Process object that maps to the browser.

At this point, I would like to obtain the URL(s) from the browser.

Thank you,

- G

Comment: I think you will find you answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=firefox+c%23+get+url

Comment: I have read those posts and I noticed that Leon Tayson mentioned a solution that used a .NET 3.5 object (he needed a .NET 2.0 soltion).  I was hoping to find some help regarding what that .NET 3.5 object (and solution) was.

Answer (score 1):

Check out these links, they should do the trick!

http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=943095&start=0&st=0&sk=t&sd=a

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Progress_Listeners

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/b1e5c626-97d9-40b3-9f98-918f2c9daa3b/